# gridview size increase(horizontly) with large content

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a gridview which increase horizontally when content is large.Anyone solve this problem.thanks 
i applied this css on my gridview...

```
table#MainContent_grdAllQuestions
{
  border-style:none; 
  width:100%;
  margin-left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the width property of the grid with fixed values. You can also set the individual column widths with percentages or fixed values

Answer (score 0):

You can provide fixed with to a gridview also you can specify each column width using itemtemplate by specifing with property.

```
    style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="1000px">  also you can apply style to the gridview
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i fixed gridview width.can u tell me how can i fix columns.

Comment: in item template you can specify column width in percentage.